# A Progressbar with three Information

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, ipad

Hi people iam new in programming objective-c for iOS. I have a big problem with progressbar. Here is my question:

I need three Information in my progress bar:

number of slides, number of
time used, and number of time left. They would be measure in percentage.
For example
if 50% of presentation time is used and I have presented 60% of my slide
then, the bar should look like
"bbbbbgyyyy" where "b - blue colour for time used", "g - green colour for
slides ahead" and "y - yellow colour for time left".

if 50% of time is used and I have only presented 30% of my slide then the
bar should look like
"bbbppyyyyy" where "b - blue colour for time used", "p - pink colour for
slides behind" and "y - yellow colour for time left".

Can anyone help me? Big thx

Comment: Stack overflow is not your personal code generator.  What have you tried?

Comment: I thought I can achieve with UIProgressBar. But now i know i need to create my own progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect can't be achieved with the standard `UIProgressBar` class, you will need to subclass or create your own control and write the logic and drawing code necessary for this. If you get stuck while implementing it, ask another qStack Overflow question, but don't expect anybody to code your app for you.